# Is it possible to reference a .NET assembly from ColdFusion?

Tags: asp.net, coldfusion

Is it possible to reference a .NET assembly from ColdFusion?  If so, how can I accomplish this?  I am not a ColdFusion developer by any means.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can call .net Assemblies directly since CF8.

Example:

```
<cfobject type=".NET" name="mathInstance" class="mathClass"
          assembly="C:/Net/Assemblies/math.dll">
<cfset myVar = mathInstance.multiply(1,2)>
```

or

```
mathInstance = CreateObject(".NET", "mathClass", "C:/Net/Assemblies/math.dll");
myVar = mathInstance.multiply(1,2);
```

[CF8 Doc - Using Microsoft .NET Assemblies](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/dotNet_01.html#1159705)

[CF9 Doc - Using Microsoft .NET Assemblies](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-715e.html)

[JNBridgePro](http://www.jnbridge.com/jnbphow.htm) is used under the hood to make this possible.  Reference: [BlueDragon.NET versus CF8 .NET Integration: Architecture](http://blog.newatlanta.com/index.cfm?mode=entry&entry=5B7F879F-EBE8-4C28-A94640C7874B7545).